# Is there a way to assign multiple key equivalents to a Menu Item in Cocoa (via IB or programmatically)?

Tags: cocoa

Specifically, I want my "New" menu item to respond to both `Cmd+N` and `Cmd+T` since it will open a new document in a tab.* How can I do this either in Interface Builder or programmatically?

** I can explain the reasoning further if needed, but I'm hoping to avoid a discussion of the merits and rather focus on how to do it, not why to do it.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a second one (easiest way being to duplicate it) and set it as hidden. It won't show up when the user pulls open the menu, but as long as it's enabled, its key equivalents should still be in effect.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be responding to the key equivalent when hidden. I'll keep looking into it though, since there may be something preventing it from being enabled in my code.

Comment: Well, I'm just explicitly returning YES in `validateMenuItem:` for its selector, and it works fine. It seems like I should be able to ensure that it is enabled in a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: You should watch session 145 from this year's WWDC: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ If you have an ADC account, you should be able to watch it even if you didn't go to the conference.

Comment: Since it's difficult to tell from the online listing, "Session 145" is called "Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications" - link via iTunes: https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345655?i=1952599232

Comment: This doesn't work for me — the keyboard shortcut does not work when the menu item is hidden.

Comment: There is a NSMenuItem property – "allowsKeyEquivalentWhenHidden: Bool".

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A simple way to have **two or more Key Equivalents** for an action is to duplicate the `NSMenuItem` and add a special **Tag** for these *"alternatives"* menu items.

Then set the `AppDelegate` the delegate (`NSMenuDelegate`) of the corresponding enclosing `NSMenu` (where the inner items need the visibility to be updated).

> **Hidden menu items** (or items with a hidden superitem) do not appear in
>   a menu and **do not participate in command key matching**.

When the `NSMenu` open, hides this alternates `NSMenuItem`, when it close, display them.

#### Example in Swift 3:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        NSApp.mainMenu?.item(withTitle: "View")?.submenu?.item(withTitle: "Zoom")?.submenu?.delegate = self
    }

    func toggleVisibility(_ visible: Bool, ofAlternatesKeyEquivalentsItems items: [NSMenuItem]) {
        for item in items.filter({ $0.tag == 2 }) {
            item.isHidden = !visible
        }
    }

    func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        if menu.title == "Zoom" {
            toggleVisibility(false, ofAlternatesKeyEquivalentsItems: menu.items)
        }
    }

    func menuDidClose(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        if menu.title == "Zoom" {
            toggleVisibility(true, ofAlternatesKeyEquivalentsItems: menu.items)
        }
    }
}
```